# Need help to create my first javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, instance, default

I have been asked to create a javascript class based on the following code :

```
 var var1=new MyClass();

 MyClass.setDefaultYear("2013"); //sets default year for all instances of MyClass to 2013

 var1.getYear(); //returns 2013

 var1.year=2001; //sets year to 2001

 var1.getYear(); //returns 2001

 var var2=new MyClass();

 var2.getYear(); //returns 2013
```

What bothers me is : `MyClass.setDefaultYear("2013")`

I have managed to make everything else work but what I do not understand is how to use `"MyClass"` instead of an instance name.

What have I missed in my self-learning process ?

Thank you

Comment: One very simple way...go to the typescript playground, make your class there and inspect the javascript compilation

Comment: Actually you are not creating a class but a prototype which is "cloned" to get new instances.

Comment: @harsha, have you ever heard of static methods or class methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exactly what you are asking.

```
       /* THIS IS THE "CLASS" */
var MyClass = (function () {

    // MyClass is a function that constructs an instance
    function MyClass() { }

    //Creates a new function on the prototype to get the year for the instance. functions which are part of the prototype are instance functions that are shared across all instances of the object.
    MyClass.prototype.getYear = function () {
        return this.year;
    }

    MyClass.setDefaultYear = function (year) {
        /* The prototype is shared across all instances of MyClass, 
        so all instances receive the same value, unless specified directly on the instance.*/
        MyClass.prototype.year = parseInt(year);
    }


    // return the full MyClass implementation.
    return MyClass;
})(); // Your "class" ends here!

// Tests...

var var1 = new MyClass(); // Create a new instance of MyClass

MyClass.setDefaultYear(2013); // Set The default year for ALL instances of MyClass.

alert(var1.getYear()); // This shows "2013" because that is what has been set on the prototype.

var1.year = 2001; //Year is visible, and you can set it's value for each unique instance.

alert(var1.getYear()); // This displays "2001" because that is the value now belonging to instance "var1"

var var2 = new MyClass(); // Create a new instance of MyClass

alert(var2.getYear()); // Since the prototypes value is still 2013, this displays "2013"
```

Comment: This helped me a lot to understand, thank you (and to others who helped me too).
La classe ! ("You rule", in French ;))

Comment: No problem! :-) JavaScript's prototypal architecture is sometimes an odd beast to handle!

Answer (score 1):

The identifier `MyClass` is the function that is used to create instances of the class. As a function is also an object (as everything else), it can have properties. So you just add a property to the object:

```
MyClass.setDefaultYear = function() { ... };
```

You also need somewhere to store the default year setting. You can make that also a member of the `MyClass` object, or you can put an immediately executed function expression around the code that creates the `setDefaultYear` method, so that you can store the default year in a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

MyClass is not defined.

```
function MyClass(){
    this.setDefaultYear = function(year){
        MyClass.prototype.year = year;
    };
    this.getYear = function (){
        return this.year;
    }
}
var var1=new MyClass();
var1.setDefaultYear("2013"); //sets default year for all instances of MyClass to 2013
console.log(var1.getYear()); //returns 2013
var1.year=2001; //sets year to 2001
console.log(var1.getYear()); //returns 2001
var var2=new MyClass();
console.log(var2.getYear()); //returns 2013
```

Comment: Your example is certainly more concise than mine. Good Job! :-)

Comment: There is something important to note here that "this.getYear" will create a new instance of that function for every instance of MyClass, whereas "MyClass.prototype.getYear" would be a shared function across all instances. The latter is slightly less expensive since each instance shares a function, which just returns than instances "year" value (see my example);

Comment: @series0ne Thanks for your advice.I modified my code, and it works more well than before.But I don't know is this absolutely correct.

Comment: Look at what the OP is asking, consider this in my answer, and compare the code in my code with yours. I can see instantly with your answer that this is not exactly what the OP is asking. You've nearly got it, however the op has specified that setDefaultYear should be acessible statically (MyClass.setDefaultYear). The function behavior is accurate but you've implemented this on the instance, not the static object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyClass(){
// other stuff
}
MyClass.setDefaultYear = function(year){
    MyClass.year = year;
}
// the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Think of `setDefaultYear` as a class function & provide default value as fallback in `getYear` function.

```
MyClass.setDefaultYear = function(year) {
  MyClass.defaultYear = year;
}

MyClass.setDefaultYear("2013");

function MyClass() {
  ....
  ....
  this.year;
  this.getYear = function() {
   return this.year || MyClass.defaultYear; //returns MyClass.defaultYear if this.year is not set.
  };
  this.setYear = function(year) {
   this.year = year;
  };
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.getYear();//"2013"
myClass.setYear("2015");
myClass.getYear();//"2015"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your class is a function named `MyClass`. In JavaScript functions are Objects. Therefore you can assign properties to functions via keyword `this`. In addition, every custom function will be exteded by a prototype attribute. This attribute is a reference to a virtual object. If you create a new instance of your MyClass via keyword `new`, you use the reference to the virtual object. You are able to extend your class/virtual object via the attribute `.prototype`. Example:

```
function MyClass(pname)
{
    this.name = pname;
}

MyClass.prototype.getName = function()
{
    alert(this.name);
}

Obj = new MyClass('Simon');
Obj.getName(); // alerts Simon
```